# Domain change - from Front end developer to salesforce

Tags: dns, frontend, salesforce

**Im working as front end dev and i have 9yr of IT experience & getting 15LPA.  Planning to change my domain from FE to salesforce developer. Is that good idea to change & will i get better package than 15L? Bcoz i'm fresher for salesforce developer?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Salesforce Lightning Platform, the primary language for front-end development is **Javascript,** **HTML, CSS** which we call **Lightning Web Components** or **Aura Component** in Salesforce, and component libraries are built with core Web Components that run natively in the browser.

Therefore you are not fresher for Salesforce Developer.

To reply to your question - *Is it a good idea to change & will I get a better package than 15L*

Salesforce has fantastic earning potential. With Salesforce customers competing for the best talent, the ecosystem's supply and demand problem is driving up wages. And, as a Salesforce Developer, you will undoubtedly benefit from the market's competitiveness, as well as, Salesforce positions—an estimated 3.3 million new jobs by end of 2022.

Yes, you can earn more salaries by coding in Salesforce! Work with this hot, new job industry and I guarantee you will get a more percentage hike if you do well.

Also, Salesforce has grown at a **25 percent annual rate over** the last four years and has ambitious plans to double its growth over the next four.

So, you can start planning to switch to a salesforce developer.

Please let me know if this answer helps your query. And also, I wish you all the best for the future :)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Avnish .  Your answer is very clear and got idea now. Thanks lot for your valuable reply.

Comment: Thanks, Mokka, Can you like this answer as solved it will help others too.

Comment: Yes Avnish. It will help others for sure.